# How to remove quotes using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have:

```
nuid="!,@,a-z"
```

But I do not want the double quotes. I want nuid=!,@,a-z

Suggest me ways to remove the start and end quotes

Here is my code:

```
sub highlight(nuid as string)

dim sh3 as worksheet

Set sh3 = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

sh3.Select

Cells.Find("User ID").Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

nuid = Replace(nuid, """", "")

Set rn = sh3.UsedRange
  k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1
  For x = 1 To k

 If ActiveCell.Value Like nuid Then

 Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow

 Else

 Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.

Next

end sub
```

From my gui, i will enter special characters which will be stored in the variable nuid.I want only the special characters and not the quotes around it

Comment: Search for [VBA and Replace](https://www.google.se/#q=VBA+replace).

Answer (score 9):

Also you can try:

`nuid = Replace(nuid, Chr(34), vbNullString)`

But you can have problem if quotes not the first nor the last character, for example: `"!,@,"a-z"`.

In that case you can try:

`nuid = Mid(nuid, 2, Len(nuid) - 1)` This will cut the first and last character

Edit:
It seems to me that the quotes that you see indicates the type of a variable string.

[image]

Edit2 - watch window

[image]

Results:

[image]

Edit3 - with sub 4 Sagi:

```
Sub Highlight4Sagi(SpecChar As String)

Dim Column As Integer
SpecChar = "!@#"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Select
Column = Cells.Find("User ID").Column

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop each row in column "User ID"
    For j = 1 To Len(SpecChar) 'loop every specchar: ! and @ and # and find him in each cells
        If InStr(1, Cells(i, Column), Mid(SpecChar, j, 1)) > 0 Then
        Cells(i, Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Exit For
        Else
        Cells(i, Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried replacing "nuid = Replace(nuid, """", "")" with "nuid = Mid(nuid, 2, Len(nuid) - 1" but still the value of nuid="!,@,a-z"

Comment: @sagi: you run this sub like this: `highlight("!,@,a-z")`? It seems to me that the quotes that you see indicates the type of a variable `string`, look to my answer

Comment: @sagi: You can add data with which you have a problem, and this procedure does not work as expected?

Comment: from my gui i enter special characters like this-!,@, this will be passed to my vb script. When it is passed it is being stored as "!,@" which i dont want

Comment: so should i change the variable type? @Dawid

Comment: @sagi: I think these quotes are the designation type of the variable `String`, I do not know what more can I say. Everything looks properly

Comment: @Sagi: I added two new pictures. Quotes did not apply in this case affect the result

Comment: Can you please tell me the code for highlighting the cell if it contains specified special characters using vba? This should be a loop.

Comment: @Sagi: look to my last edit with sub `Highlight4Sagi`, you can try to write something based on it

Answer (score 2):

Proper Function:

```
Sub Test()
 Debug.Print RemoveOuterQuotes(Cells(2, 1).Value)
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function RemoveOuterQuotes(ByVal Str As String) As String
 If Left(Str, 1) = """" Then
  Str = Right(Str, Len(Str) - 1)
 End If
 If Right(Str, 1) = """" Then
  Str = Left(Str, Len(Str) - 1)
 End If
 'Debug.Print Str
 'Stop
 RemoveOuterQuotes = Str
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically escape a `"` with `""`

Below should help

```
nuid = replace (nuid, """", "")
```

[image: Code]
[image: Output]

Comment: does not work :/ The value of nuid is still "!,@,a-z"

Answer (score 0):

additional variant

```
Sub highlight(nuid As String)
    Dim sh3 As Worksheet, Cl&, Lrow&, x&, oCell As Range
    Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Cl = sh3.Cells.Find("User ID").Column
    Frow = sh3.Cells.Find("User ID").Row + 1
    Lrow = Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    For Each oCell In sh3.Range(Cells(Frow, Cl), Cells(Lrow, Cl))
        If oCell.Value <> "" Then
            For x = 1 To Len(nuid)
                If oCell.Value Like "*" & Mid(nuid, x, 1) & "*" Then
                    oCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Exit For
                Else
                    oCell.Interior.Color = xlNone
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    Next oCell
End Sub
```

output

[image]

but if you need to find, for instance the cells which contain any char in low case  `[a-z]` then another aproach should be used